# Dynamic navigation using PHP include

Tags: php, dynamic, include, nav

I have a question about how I can dynamically change the content to display in the webpages.
I have few portions of the website fixed - header, nav, footer, and splash and a side bar.

I only want the middle portion of my website to change based on the menu link what user clicks on.

Below is my code for index.php

```
<?php
include "/templates/header.php";
include "templates/menu.php";
include "/templates/splash.php";
$action = "index"; 
$disallowed_paths = array('header','menu','splash','bottom_page', 'footer'); 
if (!empty($_GET['action'])) 
{ 
    $tmp_action = basename($_GET['action']); 
       if (!in_array($tmp_action, $disallowed_paths) && file_exists("/content/$tmp_action.php")) 
        $action = $tmp_action; 
} 
include "/content/$action.php";  
include "/templates/bottom_page.php";
include "/templates/footer.php";
?>
```

My **menu.php** contains links for **Home**, **About**, **products**, **services** and **login links**
I just want to change the **main_index.php** to `include` the above based on what user clicks on.

please advise if this approach is good.
or should I create similar file as **index.php** multiple times with includes to each file as per the link clicked on menu

Comment: take a look at smarty or simular template-systems for better understanding if you want to program vanilla or use it

Answer (score 1):

Your Answer is

> [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) method

You can use `get` method for that

```
 <ul>
        <li><a href="?page=example_1">example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=example_2">example 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=example_3">example 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=example_4">example 4</a></li>
</ul>

    After User Clicks on the link 

    <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!=""){
            $page = "";
            switch ($_GET['page']) {
                case 'example_1':
                    $page = "Page_1.php";
                    break;

                case 'example_2':
                    $page = "Page_2.php";
                    break;

                case 'example_3':
                    $page = "Page_3.php";
                    break;

                case 'example_4':
                    $page = "Page_4.php";
                    break;

                default:
                    $page = "any_default_page.php";
                    break;
            }

            include($page);
        }
     ?>
```

And there are other ways also. but this is the most easy and efficient

Answer (score 0):

I think better approach would be whitelisting instead of blacklisting.

```
$existing_pages = array('home', 'contact', 'terms-of-service'); 

if(isset($_GET['action'] && in_array($_GET['action'], $existing_pages)
{
    // load action here
} else {
    //show 404 error
}
```

Note that your overall approach is not ideal, you could look like into modern frameworks like `Laravel` or `Symphony` which has templating systems which helps alot.

But for learning purposes this is fine:)